# Show integers pulled from DB as a % inside of chartJS

Tags: php, mysql, database, charts, chart.js

I have a users progress saved into a table `studentTakingModule` in the database. I am using `chartJS` to then plot this data to show the user what % they have completed. However, I only seem to be getting one figure returned on the pie chart when there should be 6. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

The SQL query I am using is below (which pulls out the `moduleName`, `pageID` & the `completed`) is executing fine and returning the columns needed. It's the data being plotted into the chart where the issue is.

```
SELECT `studentTakingModule`.`pageID`, `studentTakingModule`.`completed`, `module`.`moduleName` 
FROM `studentTakingModule` 
INNER JOIN `module` ON `studentTakingModule`.`moduleID` = `module`.`moduleID` 
WHERE `studentID` = ?
```

There are 12 pages in each section, so, if the user has `12` under `pageID` in the table, `completed` will change to a `1` and they would have completed 100% of that section.

**The code I am using so far is this:**

```
<canvas id="progOnModules" style="width=5 height=5"></canvas>
<?php
$studentID = $_SESSION['studentID'];

$progress = [];
$moduleName = [];

$stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT `studentTakingModule`.`pageID`, `studentTakingModule`.`completed`, `module`.`moduleName` FROM `studentTakingModule` INNER JOIN `module` ON `studentTakingModule`.`moduleID` = `module`.`moduleID` WHERE `studentID` = ? ");

$stmt->bind_param("i", $studentID);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) 
        { 
            $progress[] = $row['pageID'];
            $moduleName[] = $row['moduleName'];
            $completed = $row['completed'];
         }
$modProgress = implode(',',$progress);
$modTotal = 12 - $modProgress;

$modName = json_encode($moduleName); 
$modCompleted = $completed;

// This is for the % complete
    if ($modCompleted == 1){
        $modPercent = 100;
    } else {
      $modPercent = (($modProgress-1)/12)*100;
    }
?>
```

**script for the chart:**

```
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('progOnModules').getContext('2d');
   var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'pie',
   data: {
       labels: <?php echo $modName ?>, //This is to plot the 6 names
       datasets: [{
       label: '`Modules`',
           data: [<?php echo $modPercent ?>], // This is where the 6 %'s should be
               backgroundColor: [                                   
               'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
               'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
               'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
               'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
               'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
               'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)' 
            ],
                borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
                borderWidth: 2
            }]
        },
    });
</script>
```

**Error:** *Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered*

Table Screenshot:
[image: db]

Comment: i have experience with chartjs, please provide table structure and data

Comment: Hi @yoss I'll pop a screenshot of the table in the original Question, I think the error is somewhere in the PHP code.